# React (router?) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: reactjs

When I'm trying to open React page using links like `http://www.bla.com/sdfsf` everything work as It should, but when I'm trying to reach the site using the url `http://www.bla.com/sdfsf/asdad` it fails returning me the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I've done few researches on this topic, people who had a similar problem solved it by adding property `type="text/jsx"` or `type="text/babel"` to their `script` tag, but that doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Check the network panel in chrome's developer tools. Your app is probably requesting a JS file on a relative path, which causes this error (expecting a JS file but loading an HTML file - a 404, for instance - will trigger this error).

Comment: Thank you, you were right. I indeed made a typo and my JS file has been requested by relative path and that caused my problem

Answer (score 4):

to solve this problem in my case was to change the script in the index.html

from = `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`

To = `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>`

just by adding the `'/'` before the bundle.js

i hope that solves your problem too. you mind need to add the `'/'` for every script in your index.html file

Answer (score 0):

For my version of react-scripts (^5.0.0) there is no more `<script src=` in the `index.html`.

In this case the solution was to update the `homepage` property in the `package.json` to point to the full deployed url of the app.

Before:

```
homepage: "."
```

After:

```
homepage: "https://www.coolwebsite.com"
```